# Kotlin Coroutines zip three Flows

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

There is [zip](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/zip.html) function to zip two `Flows`. Is there something to **zip three** (or more) `Flows` together?

If not, can you help me to implement extension function for it? Something like:

```
flow.zip(flow2, flow3) { a, b, c -> 

}
```

Comment: Apparently [zip is only implemented for 2, but not for 3...N](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/d7de5f5ba66a8d005e5cbd03b18522112303fd54/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/flow/internal/Combine.kt#L101-L134) but I guess you can zip the first two, then zip with next, zip with next, but it won't be as parallel as you think.

Answer (score 4):

I am new to Flows but this seems to be working for me.

```
    // This will hold all 3 values
    data class Foo(val i: Int, val j: Int, val k: Int)

    val flow1 = (1..10).asFlow()
    val flow2 = (11..20).asFlow()
    val flow3 = (21..30).asFlow()

    val combinedFlow = flow1.zip(flow2) {i, j ->  
        Pair(i, j)
    }.zip(flow3) {pair, k ->
        Foo(pair.first, pair.second, k)
    }
```

Then you would collect them and get the values out like this:

```
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repo.combinedFlow.collect {foo ->
                System.out.println(foo.i)
                System.out.println(foo.j)
                System.out.println(foo.k)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just something to note, is that `zip` will complete at the same time as the shortest `List` in your collection of 3.  But since yours are equal, all items will be collected.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the `zip` operator implementation and try to **copy/emulate** how it works adapting it to your needs.

**Test it and make all the changes you need**

```
fun <T1, T2, T3, R> Flow<T1>.zip(flow2: Flow<T2>, flow3: Flow<T3>, transform: suspend (T1, T2, T3) -> R): Flow<R> = channelFlow {

    val first: ReceiveChannel<T1> = produce {
        this@zip.collect {
            channel.send(it)
        }
    }

    val second: ReceiveChannel<T2> = produce {
        flow2.collect {
            channel.send(it)
        }
    }

    val third: ReceiveChannel<T3> = produce {
        flow3.collect {
            channel.send(it)
        }
    }

    (second as SendChannel<*>).invokeOnClose {
        if (!first.isClosedForReceive) first.cancel(MyFlowException())
        if (!third.isClosedForReceive) third.cancel(MyFlowException())
    }

    (third as SendChannel<*>).invokeOnClose {
        if (!first.isClosedForReceive) first.cancel(MyFlowException())
        if (!second.isClosedForReceive) second.cancel(MyFlowException())
    }

    val otherIterator = second.iterator()
    val anotherIterator = third.iterator()

    try {
        first.consumeEach { value ->
            if (!otherIterator.hasNext() || !anotherIterator.hasNext()) {
                return@consumeEach
            }
            send(transform(value, otherIterator.next(), anotherIterator.next()))
        }
    } catch (e: MyFlowException) {
        // complete
    } finally {
        if (!second.isClosedForReceive) second.cancel(MyFlowException())
        if (!third.isClosedForReceive) third.cancel(MyFlowException())
    }
}

class MyFlowException: CancellationException()
```

Usage:

```
flow1.zip(flow2, flow3) { a, b, c ->
    //Do your work
}...
```

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested this, but you can give it a try. There's a lot of underlying code for `zip`, so to exploit that I'm zipping the first two Flows into a Flow of Pairs, and then zip the Flow of Pairs to the third Flow. But the lambda passed to this function gets the first two already separated so it doesn't have to know about the intermediate Pair step.

```
fun <T1, T2, T3, R> zip(
    first: Flow<T1>,
    second: Flow<T2>,
    third: Flow<T3>,
    transform: suspend (T1, T2, T3) -> R
): Flow<R> =
    first.zip(second) { a, b -> a to b }
        .zip(third) { (a, b), c ->
            transform(a, b, c)
        }
```

Usage like this:

```
zip(flow1, flow2, flow3) { a, b, c ->
    Triple(a, b, c)
}
```

And here's an untested version for an arbitrary number of flows, but they have to be of the same type:

```
fun <T, R> zip(
    vararg flows: Flow<T>,
    transform: suspend (List<T>) -> R
): Flow<R> = when(flows.size) {
    0 -> error("No flows")
    1 -> flows[0].map{ transform(listOf(it)) }
    2 -> flows[0].zip(flows[1]) { a, b -> transform(listOf(a, b)) }
    else -> {
        var accFlow: Flow<List<T>> = flows[0].zip(flows[1]) { a, b -> listOf(a, b) }
        for (i in 2 until flows.size) {
            accFlow = accFlow.zip(flows[i]) { list, it ->
                list + it
            }
        }
        accFlow.map(transform)
    }
}
```